# Comparing left column with right column in excel with python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a qestion about comparing columns in python. For example:
If value from column 1 starts with "w", then add "x" to the same row in column B, but only if row in B is empty.
I know there is supposed to be an loop to filter those columns, but im quite new with pandas.

```
    INPUT
    1   2
1   w   NaN
2   w   b
3   b   b
4   w   x

OUTPUT
    1   2
1   w   x
2   w   b
3   b   b
4   w   x
```

Comment: What is `[empty]` in this case? There's no such thing in `pandas`. It's either `NaN` or a whitespace.

Comment: Please include the attempts you have made to solve this yourself.

Comment: df[2][df[2]==''] = df[1].apply(lambda t: 'x' if t[0]=='w')

Comment: `df['2']=df['2'].fillna('x)` or `df[2]=df2[2].fillna('x')` (if he column  names are numbers & not strings)

Comment: @Erfan sorry, empty means NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create both of your conditions with [`isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and [`str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html).

Then use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to fill column `2`:

```
m1 = df['1'].str.startswith('w')
m2 = df['2'].isna()

df.loc[m1&m2, '2'] = 'x'
```

**Output**

```
   1  2
1  w  x
2  w  b
3  b  b
4  w  x
```

---

*note*: I assumed your column names are strings, so I used `'1'` and `'2'`. If they are integers use `1` and `2`.